# Why does the order of the points matter when checking corresponding points with the fundamental matrix?

Tags: computer-vision, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, homogenous-transformation, fundamental-matrix

Why does the order of the points matter when calculating the correspondence between points for the fundamental matrix equation?

[image]

Here I don't understand why switching the points does not produce the same answer

[image]

My guess is that is has to do with the fact that normally you set the first camera to be the canonical camera [I 0] and that this is assumed for the image point x, but most references do not mention that the first camera P has to be [I 0].

Comment: imagine epipolar lines on your pictures. now imagine putting the lines from the _one_ view on the _other_ view instead. that wouldn't look right.

Comment: put another way: transpose the whole left side. your second equation would contain F^T instead of just F. is F = F^T?